# transition speed depends on scroll speed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im making a top navigation, that with a transition of 1s, reappears fixed after `scroll >= 300`. My jQuery looks the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= 100 && scroll < 300) {
       $("#navbar").css({ "top": "-50px", "transition": "1s ease-out"});
       $("#navbar").removeClass('navbar-static-top');
    }
    else if (scroll >= 300)
    {
       $("#navbar").addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
       $("#navbar").css({ "top": "0px", "box-shadow": "0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"});
       $("#topsection").css("padding-top", "50px");

    }
    else if (scroll < 100) {
      $("#navbar").css({ "top": "0px", "transition": "0s ease", "box-shadow": "0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4)" });
      $("#navbar").addClass('navbar-static-top');
      $("#navbar").removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      $("#topsection").css("padding-top", "0px");
    }
})
```

Unfortunately, when i scroll faster, it seems as if the transition moves faster, opposed to when i scroll slow. I really want it to be independent of my scroll speed. How do i achieve that? and why is it even acting this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll faster, scroll event fires more.
If you want to be independent of scroll speed, you should use your scroll speed like code1 or use timeout like code2.

Code 1:

```
$(window).on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
  var e0 = e.originalEvent,
    delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;
  //delta is scroll speed!

  //~~
});
```

Code 2:

```
var isFiring = false;
var interval = 200; // bigger makes slower
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(isFiring) return;
  setTimeout(function(){
    isFiring = false;
  }, interval)
  isFiring = true;

  //~~
});
```